# Как убрать клавиатуру при выходе из диалога?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-inputmethodmanager

Итак, у меня есть диалог, который открывается следующим образом:

```
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Как мы видим, при тапе на свободную от диалога часть экрана он закроется (диалог). Также, у меня есть клавиатура, настраиваемая следующим образом:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        editDisplayText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.d("keyCode", String.valueOf(keyCode));
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    String s = editDisplayText.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("enter numbers", s);
                    if (s.length() != 0) amount = Double.parseDouble(s);
                    if (amount <= 0) amount = 1;
                    alertDialog.cancel();
                    setRate();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Если я тапну по свободной части экрана, клавиатура не закроется, потому что не был отработан сценарий закрытия. Как мне убрать клавиатуру?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте один из известных мне вариантов закрытия клавы:

```
activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

.

```
try {
    View focusView = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (focusView != null) {
        focusView.clearFocus();
        ((InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        focusView.getWindowToken(), HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    String message = e.getMessage();
    Log.v("KeyBrdUtils", message == null ? "" : message);
}
```